# Combinar If en PHP con Hora

Tags: php, if

estoy modificando un sistema de reservas y quiero que no se pueda reservar para más de 24 o 48 horas de antelación.
Actualmente cuando es lunes, con el siguiente código puedo hacer reservas para toda la semana:

```
Resuelto
```

Ahora mismo lo único que hace es una vez pasados 30 minutos desde el inicio de la reserva no poder reservar.

La parte sería esta pero no consigo hacerlo

```
if($n_dia==$i && $clase_celda->int_hora <= $n_hora)
```

También estoy intentando combinarlo con que si la variable 
`<?=$cliente->caducidad?>` es < que la fecha actual, tampoco le deje pero no sé si tengo que hacerlos por separado o se pueden usar && o el OR o AND

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí lo que hace es no mostrar el botón de reservar cuando la hora actual es <= que la hora de la clase

Comment: Podrías compartir más extractos de tu código? Es dificil ayudarte sin un contexto más amplio.

Comment: Vale, creo que me expliqué un poco mal, tiene varios ifs y else dependiendo si el usuario tiene la sesión iniciada, cuando el usuario no tiene clases disponibles, actualizo el código, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final he conseguido hacerlo funcionar de la siguiente manera:

```
//Seleccionamos fecha de caducidad del cliente.
$caducidad_01 = ($cliente->caducidad);
$caducidad_02 = str_replace('/', '-', $caducidad_01);
$caducidad_final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($caducidad_02));

//Limitamos los días de reserva
$hoy = date("Y-m-d");
$limite_reserva = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($hoy . "+2 days"));
```

Y luego he puesto los siguientes ifs

```
if($dia['fecha_clase'] > $caducidad_final) {
//no se puede reservar por la caducidad
}

if($dia['fecha_clase'] > $limite_reserva) {
//No se puede reservar con más antelación de 2 días
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente por qué no usar DateTime

```
$fecha_hora_reserva = '2018-09-06 14:47:56';

// Fecha actual
$now = new DateTime('NOW'); // Fecha hora actual

// Si es domingo incrementamos la fecha actual en 1 dia
if($now->format('N') == 7) {
    $now->modify('+1 day'); // Sumas un dia
    $now->setTime(7, 0, 0); // Estableces hora a las 7am
}

// Fecha de la reserva
$reserva = new DateTime($fecha_hora_reserva);

// Diferencia
$diff = $now->diff($reserva); // obtienes la diferencia

// calculamos los minutos para ajustar la precisión
$diff_minute = $diff->format('%i'); // minutos
$diff_minute += $diff->format('%h')*60;  // horas
$diff_minute += $diff->format('%a')*1440; // dias

// comprobamos el rango de horas
if(2880 >= $diff_minute) {
    echo 'menor o igual a 2 días(48h)';
} else { 
    echo 'mayor a 2 días(48h)';
}
```

Comment: Vale gracias, en crudo solamente eso me funciona pero no consigo adaptarla al código que envié, cuál sería el orden correcto? 
los valores son `$dia['nombre'],$hora`

Comment: @Jesús a que te refieres con los valores correctos??

Comment: me refiero que no consigo adaptar tu código al código que envié no consigo como modificar el $fecha_hora reserva para que funcione en mi código

Comment: @Jesús Y cuales son tus datos de entrada, no te puedo especificar mas sin conocer mas el contexto y mas detalles.

Comment: los datos son los que tengo en el código que puse arriba, realmente lo que hace es que muestre o no un botón para reservar, te adjunto imagen para que lo veas más claro, gracias

Comment: @Jesús realmente en tu pregunta no queda nada claro, el código es bastante espagueti, no lo tomes a mal, y para alguien que no conoce el proyecto es difícil saber de donde salen los datos, que formato tienen y cual es el resultado esperado, además de ser u  trozo sin contexto. La imagen no apoya mucho. Normalmente al trabajar con fechas el formato estándar es `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` aún que a la hora de mostrarlo lo formatees de otra forma.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el código por el de la página al completo, gracias por tu ayuda, soy usuario novato y estoy aprendiendo cosillas poco a poco, en resumen lo que pretendo es que si la clase empieza en más de x tiempo no aparezca botón de reservar y que si `$cliente->caducidad` es > que la fecha clase tampoco aparezca el botón, no sé si me expliqué correctamente, muchas gracias por todo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82685/discussion-between-jesus-and-xerif).